# Clojure multimethod dispatch by java generics

Tags: java, generics, clojure, dispatch, multimethod

### Possible solution that I need:

How to implement a multimethod for a collection of type like `Map<javaType, javaType>`? Something like this:

```clj
(defmethod multimethod Map<javaType,javaType> [map]
  {(.key (first map)) (.value (first map))})
```

---

### Whole explanation of my problem

*Maybe the question above is not the solution I need to solve my problem (it's just I think that the implementation with generics can solve my problem), so I think I need to provide the whole explanation of what is my problem and ask community what I need to do.*

I work with a java library in Clojure. Some functions return me java classes that I want to convert to clojure maps. I'm doing this with [java.data](https://github.com/clojure/java.data) library.

In most of cases this works fine. For some reason I need to implement java.data multimethod for several classes:

```clj
;; From java.data readme
(defmethod from-java YourJavaClass [instance]
  ; your custom logic for turing this instance into a clojure data structure)
```

But it's okay and this works fine:

```clj
(defmethod jd/from-java CurrencyPair [instance]
  (help/convert-market-keyword (.toString instance)))
```

But I encountered some class that can't be "mapped" for some reason.

```clj
(defmethod jd/from-java AccountInfo [instance]
  {:myWallet (jd/from-java (.getWallet instance))})

(defmethod jd/from-java Wallet [instance]
  {:myBalances (jd/from-java (.getBalances instance))})

(defmethod jd/from-java Balance [instance]
  "BALANCE!!!!") 

(defmethod jd/from-java Currency [instance]
  ;; e.g. converts Currency instance with field "BTC" to keyword :btc
  (help/convert-currency-keyword (.toString instance)))
```

After mapping an `AccountInfo` instance I expect to see this:

```clj
{:myWallet 
  {:myBalances 
    {:btc "BALANCE!!!!"
     :eth "BALANCE!!!!"
     :usdt "BALANCE!!!!"
     ...}
```

But see this:

```clj
{:myWallet 
  {:myBalances 
    {#object[org.knowm.xchange.currency.Currency 0x4faae851 "BTC"] 
     #object[org.knowm.xchange.dto.account.Balance 0x42942aa9 "Balance [currency=GNT, total=null, available=0E-8, frozen=0E-8, borrowed=0, loaned=0, withdrawing=0, depositing=0]"],

     #object[org.knowm.xchange.currency.Currency 0x299d00e0 "ETH"] 
     #object[org.knowm.xchange.dto.account.Balance 0x23f7cb1d "Balance [currency=LSK, total=null, available=0E-8, frozen=0E-8, borrowed=0, loaned=0, withdrawing=0, depositing=0]"],
     ...}
```

The returning value type of `.getBalances()` is `Map<Currency,Balance>` and it seems java.data don't know how to work with maps.

So, my question (at the moment) is how to implement the java.data multimethod for this kind of collection. Something like this:

```clj
(defmethod jd/from-java Map<Currency,Balance> [instance]
  {:cur "BALANCE!!!!"})
```

---

Just in case, the java library is XChange. The problem with [Wallet](http://knowm.org/javadocs/xchange/org/knowm/xchange/dto/account/Wallet.html) class. Method getBalances().

Comment: Generic type information is not available at runtime in Java (or Clojure) due to a process called ‘type erasure’ (stripping of generic type information during compilation). Perhaps do the transformation manually with [`clojure.walk`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.walk-api.html) and [`bean`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/bean) and custom handling of the `:balances` entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, using "generic types" at runtime is probably a non-starter. However, [it appears](https://github.com/clojure/java.data/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/java/data.clj#L170) that the java.data library does not call `from-java` recursively on keys and values in `Map` instances. The default implementation of `from-java` for `Map` is just `(into {} instance)`. Perhaps the specific problem the OP is facing can be solved by redefining `from-java` method for `java.util.Map`. The new implementation would apply `from-java` to all keys and values. For example:

```
(defmethod jd/from-java java.util.Map
  [m]
  (zipmap (map jd/from-java (keys m)) (map jd/from-java (vals m))))
```

Comment: Suure.. I've tried to implement the IPersistentMap, but didn't guess about the java.util.Map. Thanks!